# How can I find a specific value in an object?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a Parameters that is an object and contains a few value :

| key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple |
| 1 | Juice |
| 2 | Banana |

So If I do `Parameters!MyParam.Value(0)` the result is `Apple`, and `Parameters!MyParam.Value(1)` the result is `Juice`, etc.

What I want to do is to see if my object contains a value like `Banana` and return `true` if it does.

Is it possible ? I didn't find anything the net. The closest thing that I found is `inStr` but it only works for strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to point out here...

In SSRS a parameter is made up of a Value and a Label. What you describe as the Key would be the Value and what you describe as the Value would be the Label.

You can reference the Parameter's Label property using Parameters!MyParam.Label

It's not clear from your question but I assume you want to search your parameters to see if a specific value has been selected. If so then you can do that like this...

For this exmaple I have added the parameters values/labels manually but you can do this however you need.

[image]

Next I added, for demonstration purposes, some labels and fields to the report as follows.

[image]

The selected parameter's expression is

```
="|" & JOIN(Parameters!MyParam.Label, "|") & "|"
```

The 'contains banana' expression is

```
=("|" & JOIN(Parameters!MyParam.Label, "|") & "|").Contains("|Banana|")
```

The JOIN simply joins all the selected parameter labels togther, using the pipe symbol `|` as a delimiter. I then add a `|` to the start and end so the can search for `|searchterm|`. This avoids errors if, for example, you had "Pineapple" and "apple" in the parameter list and searched for "apple", it would show true even if only "pineapple" had been selected. By searching for "|apple|" we avoid this.

Once we have the join results we can then use the VB function `.Contains()` to search for what we want.

If I run the report and select all values I get this

[image]

If I select only Apple and Juice I get this

[image]